# how to change Button background in Custom adapter on Its onClick?

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I am trying to change UI of button in custom adapter click, I am able to do functional thing on particular button click event. But when I tried to change UI of any Button, it reflects to last added Button. 
I tried with setTag() option too.

Comment: check the position and change the color for the particular button.

Comment: change it with the particular position of the button or post your code for better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer by myself. 
When any Inflator and Holder used in Custom adapter, you need to create new Object for every single row (data), so you can access any item belongs to their family.

Comment: @ Rahul Upadhyay Hi I am facing the same issue Could you please tell me how to implement it

Comment: Hi, are you using any adapter? If yes then in getView() method, create new object and use it.

Answer (score 1):

use `V.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.drawableName);`

it worked for me, where the `drawable` name is the background resource in your drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the background of button inside onClick event like this :

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     v.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
                }
            });
```

Comment: You are right buddy, but I know tat how to change background. You didn't get my Question. Thanks for the help. :)